# How to hide Iframe if the same button is clicked again or other button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can show my other webpage through iframe, but how can I make it invisible or terminate the web page when the same button is clicked again

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function showIFrame() {  
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  
 iframe.style.display="block";  
}  
</script>
<style>
#myiframe {
display:none; }
</style>
<body>
<iframe id="myframe" name="carsearch" width="535" height="625" scrolling="no"   frameborder="0"></iframe>
<form name="search" id="search" method="get" action="../crime_map/map_crime_pending.php" target="carsearch">

<button type="submit" id="SearchCarButton" class="submitBtn" onclick="showIFrame()"/>  <span>Search</span></button></form>
<button>Catcher</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

try this code that check the display, and change it based in the current status;

```
   function showIFrame() {  
      var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  
      var d = iframe.style.display;
      if(d=="block"){
         iframe.style.display = "none"  
      }else{
        iframe.style.display = "block";
      }
}
```